# Socket.io Performance optimisation 15'000 users

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, websocket, socket.io

I have a chat application with huge chatrooms (15'000 user connected to one single room).
Only few have the right to write, so theoretically there should not be a huge load.
I have noticed that there are performance issue: when only one message is send, the server CPU load spikes to 30%-50% and the message gets delivered slowly (maybe 1 second later or worse if you write multiple messages)
I have analysed the performance with clinic-flame. I see that this code is the problem:
`socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);` which will trigger `send()` in engine.io and  `clearBuffer` in the `ws` library.

Does someone know if I am doing something wrong and how to optimize the performance?

[image: flame graph]

Comment: Generally speaking, a single broadcast to 15k users does require 15k messages to be sent to 15k separate connections. Completing that in under 1 second with a 30% CPU spike is fairly decent I’d say, depending on the machine it’s running on. Having said that, there may be some things you can optimize to make that work even better, which somebody more familiar with socket.io may be able to elaborate on.

Comment: Thank you @deceze. It's cleat the it generates some load, but I am impressed about the amount. Sending 3 messages completley freezes the server for 1-2 seconds.
I have tried with `eiows`, using a custom parser, installing `bufferutil` and `utf-8-validate` but there is not massive improvement. Also sending the messages as Volatile doesn't help much.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have explicit expierence with socket.io but would like through in a more general idear for a solution. How about you build 2 layers of servers.
layer 1 is kind of a master and layer 2 servers are slaves which are connected by socket.
Users get randomly connected to layer2 slaves. 
If users sends a message the layer 2 slave emits the message to all clients directly connected to it and to the layer 1 master. The master emits the message to all slaves.
If slaves recieve message from master it passes it through to their clients. You may even autoscale this setup...

Comment: thank you @TedtB, i was thinking of something similar with Clustering or child processes. I don't know if users can be connected to the same Room while beeng on different threads... but even if they are all in the same thread at least the main process won't be blocked. I will look into this

Comment: You might also have a try with setting your socket.io engine to uWebSockets. See here: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets and here: https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-4-4-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load balance sokets.io servers.

I haven't do this yet, but you have informations about doing this here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes

If you use node.js as http server : https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes#using-nodejs-cluster

Alternatively, you can consider using redis for that. There is a package that allow to distribute trafic on a cluster of process or server:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-adapter

Comment: Probably load balancing is the only option. Sadly this means a massive refactoring.
Thank you for everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to manage load balance if you have up to 15k to 20k Users, follow the below instructions.

1. In socket code do not use await async.
2. In socket code do not use any DB query.
3. Use a socket to take data from someone and provide those data to others, if you want to store those data do it using APIs before or after you send it to the socket.

It's all about how you use it. queries and await all this will slow your response and load, there is always a way to do things differently.

The above 3 suggestions boost my socket performance, I hope it does the same for you.

Comment: can you explain the reason behind "In socket code do not use await async". anyway I don't store any data and have no additional api. As you can see in the Flame Graph, only this function is causing the huge load: `socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);`

Comment: Let's consider 15 users are connected to a socket, so 15 times the query executes it takes time to execute the query when you have a small number of users it won't cause problems but with a large audience you will face many problems. The same thing happens with await async.

Comment: socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);
The above statement is in the loop?
If not then there must some statement above socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */); which is taking time to execute, can you share your whole event?

Comment: `socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... /); ` will be executed only once. so there is only one async/await. I don't think this is the problem.
Internally socket.io has some sort of for loop in order to send the message to the 15'000 users. I don't have any DB query in my code. Only one single `emit`

Comment: remove async and await and just use the following statement and tell me what's the effect.
io.to("room1").emit("your event", "your data");

Comment: done, same result. Flame graph looks the same

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: are you familiar with socket.io? there is no more code to send a message. actually I tried with many different emits: https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/ always the same result. The key part is that we have 15'000 user connected to on single room. Have you ever tried this? I am using a Server with 20 virtual machines to generates this huge load. Have you looked at the flame graph?

Comment: I appreciate the time you take and you are really kind,  but I feel like you are misunderstanding the problem and where the load comes from.

Comment: Yes I have used Socket.Io with chat app with location tracking app and with many more app, and i have divided users to several rooms.

Comment: yeah that's the difference, I have massive rooms (like Twitch) where up to 15'000 users are connected. I guess this is a limitation of WebSockets... Thank you dhaval-italiya